# using two outlets as extension cord

Tags: electrical, receptacle, generator

I'm helping a friend build a cabin and we have a generator. I was wondering if I could wire an outlet on the outside of the cabin and another inside. The outside outlet would be for power in and the one inside for power back out, basically utilizing the two outlets as an "extension cable". Obviously we could just run a cable in the house but that doesn't look nearly as good. I'm also thinking of splitting off the wire and running a single light. Does this sounds plausible?

Comment: Just to be clear...is the generator the only source of power? It sounds like you don't have power from the electric grid. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, its a remote cabin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, and I've done this myself.

But not two outlets.  **The generator side one is an *inlet***.

[image]

(These also come in a form-factor that is the same as an outlet).

From the inlet, you use in-the-wall wiring to go to as many outlets and lights as makes sense for a single circuit.

If you want 2 circuits, you can have 2 inlets, and plug each one into a different pole on the generator.

If you want >=2 circuits, you can have 1 inlet that is 20/30A 120/240V such as a NEMA 14-20 or 14-30, and then feed that into a **service panel** in the house.  From there you can branch off as many circuits as you please!

PS. Once you get sick of hauling in fuel and maintaining the generator, look into solar+battery systems, and wire as many loads as possible to be able to work on low voltage DC.  Lighting at the very least. LED lighting is your friend.

Comment: Just curious if there is a difference between an inlet/outlet or is it just the fact it's male vs female. I feel like they are both just wire carring electricity, but I'm extremly new to wiring, just got my place a few months ago and have been learing ever since

Comment: The difference is that you don't want exposed metal pins carrying mains voltage after you unplug it. The side with the power should be the "innie".

Comment: I understand, so probably would work with a outlet but not safe. Just to be clear, I would use the 30A inlet then branch off to a 15A outlet and 1 light fixture. Does that sound correct? I'm not sure we plan on needing much juice, not sure if Generators have breakers or not, but figure if we tried to run to much on the line it would just not work, there is some sort of "Fail-safe" in the Generator for too high a load.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm thinking of buying, great help as always! --> https://www.amazon.ca/Kohree-Power-Twist-Stainless-Screws/dp/B07K1SQ6JM/ref=cm_wl_huc_item

Comment: Going with a split-phase 30A plug is definitely nice, it will let you upgrade the generator eventually for very little cost, and the twist-lock connection reduces risks of sparking by preventing the plug from backing out. You should still install a small distribution panel with circuit breakers anyhow. The breakers on the generator should be regarded as protection for the generator, not the circuits in the house.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, also, regarding exposed metal, it is absolutely a safety issue. An extension cord that has two "male" plugs is often called a widowmaker. In America, we use 120V which is not nearly as dangerous as 240V, but it still poses the risk of starting fires if the energized bits that you are carefully staying away from come in contact with flammable materials. What if the plug loosens up and falls into a puddle?

Comment: @sleblanc I've always called those car jacks that are like `<>` widowmakers, I guess every trade has a widowmaker! I doubt we will do a circuit breaker, the cabin is like around 130 sq ft. 1 Light and 1 outlet will be plenty of juice.

Comment: The issue with going without a circuit breaker is that if your wiring is AWG 14 (15A) and your genny can push out 30A, a short might be enough for wires to catch on fire without tripping the overcurrent protection. An outdoor-rated 6-space (12 circuit) Square D (reputable brand) box is only $17.48 at the leading American home improvement store, and a breaker is about $10, assuming you don't already have a few spares around. You would only have to run a wire from the box to the circuit you want to power, either to an existing junction box, or you can splice it anywhere and add a junction box.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Abusing an outlet to act as an inlet would require an extension cord with two male ends.  These are called ["suicide cables"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suicide_cable) for good reason.

Comment: In addition to a [larger than you think needed] breaker box, wiring in a "transfer switch" or "Source selector" from the start may also be worth considering if you suspect someone may want to add a second input source [such as solar] as it will be less likely to end up with that input socket becoming an exposed live output.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers if you only have 1 light and 1 outlet, then don't waste your money on a 30A/240V (NEMA 14-30) inlet, just use a common 15A/120V inlet (NEMA 5-15). Plug that into one of the generator's 120V sockets with any common extension cord...

Comment: I'd just like to add, I read somewhere else on stack Exchange to act as if what would a professional do. Therefore I'm going to do it right with a 30 amp Inlet and a breaker box.